# Save HTML table data as Excel while keeping the styling?

Tags: php, html, excel

I got a page that generates a table of data based on the values provided in the form thanks to PHP script. I want to be able to save that table as Excel file, with background and text colors retained. After searching around I found that you can't keep the formatting data in CSV.

**Is there a way to export an HTML table to Excel with font style and background colors for cells preserved?**

My styling for the table goes like so:
Headers for the table have bold font and light green background for cells. Cells(rows and columns) that contain the actual data are just plain white background and black regular font.

Pseudo code of table generating function:

```
function generateReport($data){
            if(isset($data)){
                echo $header;
                echo '<table>';
                foreach($data->row as $row){
                    // here I have classes applied to tr, td tags
                    // then in css I give styling instructions
                    echo $row->data;
                }
                echo '</table>';
            }
        }
```

Comment: It should work fine if you echo the `<style>` element also.

Comment: Styling information is in styles.css which I link to the script. I'm trying to save HTML table as Excel. And keep the styling. CSV doesn't preserve the styling, just raw data with ",".

Comment: No you can't use external styles for you Excel. You must use inline styles to have your styles preserved. Just notice to use border: 0.5pt solid #333; to have Excel correct borders.

Comment: You do not need to use inline style. Classes work just fine. Also the method of deliver does matter. Here is a fun link: http://jsfiddle.net/mLx6T/show/

Comment: So, what you're saying is echo inline styling together with actual data and then when imported into excel all HTML tags will be transformed into actual styling leaving only the data in the cells without any tags?

Comment: Still, background-color doesn't transfer over for some reason to the excel. Cells just become white. EDIT: I think using the hex colors will work. Instead of just names liker ed, or green.

Comment: If you go backwords and save an Excel file as HTML you'll probably glean a lot of what can/can't be done.